# gcc C++ with -mx32 switch - how to get going on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, gcc, wxwidgets, 32bit-64bit, ubuntu-20.04

I have a substantial **C++ implementation of 32-bit Forth** for robot control, running on an **emedded ESP32** (xtensa) platform. The target is cross compiled using gcc.

I would like to provide an emulator, running on 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, using as much of the same source code as possible, and concluded that the -mx32 option would result in 32-bit integers and 32-bit pointers - perfect.

I find that **not even the simplest 'Hello, World' console program will compile** with the -mx32 switch, and the references I find to getting this option to work look highly complicated, from recompiling the C/C++ libraries to even recompiling the Linux kernel.

Also, I am using the **wxWidgets** library for GUI support.

Has anyone any experience in getting the 32-bit pointer option to work with gcc C++, and if so, are there any serious pitfalls? Or is this just a bad idea?

Thanks in advance, Peter.

Comment: `x32` is a separate architecture (32-bit code in 64-bit CPU mode) and needs its own libraries, etc. I would probably go for `-m32` instead. Which compiles 32-bit code (good old i386) and again needs its own libraries... You should get compiler support for both if you install the `-multilib` [variant of gcc](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=g%2B%2B-multilib&searchon=names).

Comment: Thanks, dratenik, for the advice. I was already looking at simply compiling 32-bit code as an alternative, and that seems better supported.

Comment: @PeterBaldock, is `-mx32` option architecture-specific? I know nothing about embedded ESP32 platform, but it seems that you want to compile the code that should run on the regular distribution with the platform specific option.

Comment: Looks like you have to recompile the kernel to be "multilib" for it or something: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121424/linux-and-x32-abi-how-to-use

Comment: @PeterBaldock, you need to set Ubuntu as `multilib` to support both 33 and 64 bit architecture.  However at this point I'd ask myself if doing so is really worth the effort. Why not use 64 bit libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the mx32 option to compile a "forth like" language I have implemented. So I have experience in it and was generally working, but there are complications with libraries. More over that happened years ago and actually I don't know the state of mx32 support. By the way I too use esp32.